# Lightyear requireFailure does not do backtracking

Tags: idris, parser-combinators, lightyear

I want to parse a series of any 4 chars. However, these chars shouldn't form a specific string ( `"bb"` in an example below). So `"aaaa"` and `"abcd"` are okay, but neither `"bbcd"` nor `"abbc"` should not match.

I composed a following parser:

```
ntimes 4 (requireFailure (string "bb") *> anyChar)
```

However, I noticed, that it "eats" single `b` chars. E.g.

```
parse (ntimes 4 (requireFailure (string "bb") *> anyToken)) "abcde"
```

results in `['a', 'c', 'd', 'e']` (it fails, however, on `"bbcd"` and `"abbc"` as expected).

As a workaround I used my own implementation of `requireFailure`:

```
requireFailure' : Parser a -> Parser ()
requireFailure' p = do
    isP <- p *> pure True <|> pure False
    if isP then fail "argument parser to fail"
           else pure ()
```

So

```
parse (ntimes 4 (requireFailure' (string "bb") *> anyToken)) "abcde"
```

gives `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']` as I expect.

Apparently lightyear parsers are [backtrack-by-default](https://github.com/ziman/lightyear#commitment), unless one calls  `commitTo`.

So my question is why library implementation of `requireFailure` does not do backtracking in case it's argument fails and is it an expected behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at [the implementation of `requireFailure`](https://github.com/ziman/lightyear/blob/master/Lightyear/Core.idr#L211) you can see that it calls the "success" continuation `us` with the state `s` it gets *after* running its argument rather than the one `ST i pos tw` it got before.

```
requireFailure : ParserT str m tok -> ParserT str m ()
requireFailure (PT f) = PT $ \r, us, cs, ue, ce, (ST i pos tw) =>
                               f r
                                 (\t, s => ue [Err pos "argument parser to fail"] s)
                                 (\t, s => ce [Err pos "argument parser to fail"] s)
                                 (\errs, s => us () s)
                                 (\errs, s => cs () s)
                                 (ST i pos tw)
```

The documentation claims that `requireFailure` is called `notFollowedBy` in parsec and [that doesn't consume any input](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.13.0/docs/Text-Parsec-Combinator.html#v:notFollowedBy) so you could argue it's a bug on LightYear's side.

You could open a bug report suggesting to replace the current code with something like (I don't know whether Idris supports `@` patterns):

```
requireFailure : ParserT str m tok -> ParserT str m ()
requireFailure (PT f) = PT $ \r, us, cs, ue, ce, s@(ST i pos tw) =>
                               f r
                                 (\t, s => ue [Err pos "argument parser to fail"] s)
                                 (\t, s => ce [Err pos "argument parser to fail"] s)
                                 (\errs, _ => us () s)
                                 (\errs, _ => cs () s)
                                 s
```

Comment: Makes sense. I created a bug report - https://github.com/ziman/lightyear/issues/66